# Javascript hide DIV HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey I can hide my divs but my problem is if I reload my page I always see the hidden div for one second.

Do someone know how to fix that?

Comment: share your code

Comment: Would you like to review your answers and accept one of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tackle this kind of issue, you need to have the `<div>` with an attribute `hidden` or something in the inline. Then you need to hide it with JS and the remove the inline thing.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".hide").hide().removeClass("hide");
});
```

```css
.hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hide">I am not shown</div>
```

Method 2: Using `hidden` attribute.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".hide").hide().removeAttr("hidden");
});
```

```css
.hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div hidden>I am not shown</div>
```

Method 3: Using `hidden` attribute and `.prop()`.

```js
$(function () {
  $(".hide").hide().prop("hidden", false);
});
```

```css
.hide {display: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div hidden>I am not shown</div>
```

Comment: i love the fact that you turned this in a snippet so we could see nothing

Comment: @Ivaro18 Ha ha ha... Evil Smile.

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS that you apply to your div, add:

```
display:none;
```

So the div will be loaded but invisible. When you need to you it, you can do as you are doing now

Answer (score 0):

Just add hidden attribute to your div and it should fix your problem then remove it by javascript when you want to show it

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myDiv').hide();
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="myDiv"><p>hello</p></div>
  </body>
```

Yes you can create the div by javascript.

```js
var div = document.createElement("Div");
var text = document.createTextNode("this is my Div")
div.appendChild(text);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<body>
  </body>
```

Comment: No! Not the answer.

Comment: You shouldn't create DOM elements using client-side Javascript unless you need to; especially not when the solution is as simple as one line of CSS.

Comment: As far as I know any time while javascript will run you will see the div.Until you hide it.

Comment: It will work, sure, but it's complete overkill as an answer to the question - people should not be using 4 lines of JS for something they can achieve using two words and a colon in CSS.

Comment: I try to answer as simple as possible.

Comment: I could see one second, that the div is being displayed.

Comment: because the first will be loaded your document and then javascript,I have same kind and problem .I solve it by no loading div and after some logic adding div element with it's css styles

Comment: It may be 'simpler' than your original answer; that doesn't change the fact that you should not be hiding a div using JavaScript at all in this case, you should be using CSS. You're bringing a hand-grenade to a snowball fight.

Comment: Why you need to have dive in html. But after page load you will hide it?

Comment: Can you please explain me ? You can have only one case that after some logic you will show the div.You can create div element after that logic and it will solve your problem

Comment: The problem can be much, much more easily solved by using `display: none` in the CSS. There is no need to use JS to create a new div at all. One line of CSS, which will be very quickly parsed by the browser, is a much better option than writing an entire JS function just to hide a single div.

Comment: yes if it's ok to use css for him.And he don't want to use javascript it is very simple solution

Comment: I can't imagine any normal situation where it would be okay for someone to use JS but not CSS.